# file_get_content(converting to htmlspecialchars)

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-get-contents

So I have this url http://my-server.com/feeds/feed.pl?op=retrieveIncidents&type=social,government&cbsa=31100 that contains xml data built by another process. Now I was using `file_get_contents()` with the url hardcoded and it worked perfectly. At this stage of dev I had to start using the config files and the cbsa codes from the current user logged in the application.

Now this `/feeds/feed.pl?op=retrieveIncidents&type=social,government&cbsa=` comes from the config.

This `31100` comes from the user object.

This `http://my-server.com` comes from a helper fn().

```
$server = $this->serverUrl();
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
$curOperator = Default_Model_Operator::getActiveOperator();

$feedUrl = $server.$config->ims->idfFeed.$curOperator->regions;
```

If I print/echo `$feedUrl`looks like `http://my-server.com/feeds/feed.pl?op=retrieveIncidents&type=social,government&cbsa=31100`

But when I do `$feed = file_get_contents($feedUrl)` I get 

**Warning**:  file_get_contents(http://vdot.orion.meridian-enviro.com/feeds/feed.pl?op=retrieveIncidents`&amp;`type=social,government`&amp;`cbsa=31100) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in **/home/Agena/lvegerano/svn/webapps/ims/trunk/phpfiles/application/views/scripts/chp/list-for-dashboard.phtml** on line **9**

Make note of the `&amp;`. I have tried `htmlentities_decode()`,`urlencode()`and other and cant get this to works. What can I do so file_get_contents() translate `&amp;`to`&`?

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to decode entities before using `file_get_contents`. When you output the url, its likely the browser is decoding the entities, but if you were to view source, the entities will be visible.

Comment: I already tried `$feedUrl = htmlspecialchars_decode($feedUrl);` before `file_get_contents()` does not work.

Comment: what is the resulting url after you run it through decode?

Comment: `http://my-server.com/feeds/feed.pl?op=retrieveIncidents&type=social,government&cbsa=31100` weird isnt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I forgot to answer this. The problem was our varnish setup. It is setup to lookup urls and if recognized inserts the host name. Because I had just started working here I was not aware of this feature. Therefore the error I thought it was it wasn't since the varnish was masking the url.